# Does Disciple of Life work with spells cast from a Staff of Healing?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, cleric, healing

If I have a Cleric who is Life domain and a Staff of Healing does Disciple of Life work with the spells cast from the Staff?

> Staff of Healing:  While holding it, you can use an action to expend 1 or more of its charges to cast one of the following spells from it, using your spell save DC and spellcasting ability modifier: [spells follow]

> Disciple of Life: Also starting at 1st level, your healing spells are more effective. Whenever you use a spell of 1st level or higher to restore hit points to a creature, the creature regains additional hit points equal to 2 + the spell’s level

Answer (score 5):

Yes, Disciple of Life applies to spells from the staff.

The staff ultimately allows *you* to cast the spells from it ("you can use an action to [...] cast one of the following spells from it"), and Disciple of Life applies to all spells you cast; it makes no restrictions along the lines of 'Whenever you use a *cleric* spell of 1st level or higher' that would prevent it from applying to the staff's spells.

Comment: '...a *Cleric* spell...' but would it prevent that though? If Healing Word was on the Cleric Spell List and prepared (or not) isnt Healing Word cast by anything the Cleric is wielding or wearing a cleric spell for all intents and purposes?

Comment: @Airatome I don't believe so; my understanding is that something is considered a {class} spell when you have it known and/or prepared from one of your classes and when you cast it through a class feature. Even if you had it prepared that day, an instance cast from the staff wouldn't be a {class} spell since it's not a class feature that you're casting it through. That said, I'd be behind asking the question "What makes something considered to be a 'class' spell?", as that's just my understanding.

Comment: You may be right...I think this definitely warrants a new question. Feel free to ask it as I can not accurately typw a question on my phone :( . Im curious the answer(s)

Comment: @Airatome I've placed the question [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell).