# Could a Wild Magic Surge be triggered by a Wild Magic Sorcerer using a Magic Initiate spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, class-feature, sorcerer, wild-magic

Under Wild Magic Surge it states:

> Immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of first level or higher, the DM can have you roll a d20.

Since Magic Initiate has you choose spells from a specific class, would a Wild Magic Sorcerer theoretically be able to Wild Magic Surge when casting those spells, assuming they chose from the sorcerer list?

Comment: Related: "[Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954)"

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Yes

The key part of the Wild Magic Surge language is **cast a sorcerer spell**.

If you had used Magic Initiate to gain spells from another class, those would not be considered sorcerer spells (supported by the language in magic initiate below from PHB, 168)

> Your spellcasting ability for these spells depends on the class you chose

But a Sorcerer spell is a sorcerer spell, and if you picked your Magic Initiate spells from Sorcerer, then they'd be potentials for Wild Magic surges.

Everything is kept within the sorcerer class and spell list, it all fits under the sorcerer umbrella.

Comment: Would this apply to spells learned via Ritual Caster that are a part of the Sorcerer spell list?

Comment: @Necronomicronic Checks all the boxes in support of yea, and here is a question we have about it: [Can a Wild Magic sorcerer trigger Wild Magic Surges with rituals?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111884/can-a-wild-magic-sorcerer-trigger-wild-magic-surges-with-rituals) :)