# If I take the Magic Initiate feat and choose a different class, but pick a spell that's also on my class's list, can I cast it using spell slots?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, class, spellcasting

If I take the Magic Initiate feat and choose a different class's spell list, but pick a spell that's also on my class's spell list, can I cast it using my class's spell slots?

I have read this question and answer: [Can you cast a magic initiate spell using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68451/can-you-cast-a-magic-initiate-spell-using-spell-slots)

If a Druid takes the Magic Initiate feat, choosing the Cleric list, and takes a spell that's on both lists (such as Healing Word), can they cast that shared spell taken from the Cleric list with their class's spell slots?

The following leads me to think this is subtly different: the previous question dealt with a wizard taking a spell that was not a wizard spell. It was Not On His List. The Druid is taking a Druid spell off the Cleric list; it is still a Druid spell and available for the Druid to prepare.

Comment: Possibly also related: [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182/15614)

Comment: Related: "[Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954)"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## No

As the the [Sage Advice Compendium ruling](https://media.wizards.com/2019/dnd/downloads/SA-Compendium.pdf#page=8) states:

> **If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st-level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?**
>
> Yes, but only if the class you pick for the feat is one of your classes.

The fact that the same spell appears on your druid spell list doesn't change that. You can still prepare and cast it as a druid, but you can't use druid spell slots to cast it when you only have it available via the Magic Initiate feat.

Comment: It may also be worth referencing the fact that [the 2018 PHB errata](http://media.wizards.com/2018/dnd/downloads/PH-Errata.pdf) changed each class's spellcasting feature to say that you can only use that class's slots to cast spells of that class (e.g. [druid's Spellcasting feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/druid#Spellcasting-166) says "The Druid table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your druid spells of 1st level and higher."). This further backs up the ruling that was in the SAC.