# If my wizard learns Dissonant Whispers from Fey Touched, is it a Wizard Spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, wizard

Note: This is a possible duplicate of [Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954/are-spells-learned-from-feats-considered-to-be-associated-with-your-class), but I couldn't find any relevant answers there.

=====================

I'm playing an Order of Scribes Wizard and picked up Fey Touched (Dissonant Whispers). Fey Touched states that I can cast Misty Step and Dissonant Whispers once each per day, but I can also "cast these spells using spell slots you have of the appropriate level." In addition, it states that I "learn" these spells. Does this means *Dissonant Whispers* is a wizard spell for me? If so, can/must I copy it into my spellbook to be able to deal psychic damage with my 1st-level spells?

> Fey Touched
>
> Your exposure to the Feywild's magic has changed you, granting you the following benefits:
>
> - Increase your Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma score by 1, to a maximum of 20.
> - You learn the Misty Step spell and one 1st-level spell of your choice. The 1st-level spell must be from the Divination or Enchantment school of magic. You can cast each of these spells without expending a spell slot. Once you cast either of these spells in this way, you can't cast that spell in this way again until you finish a long rest. You can also cast these spells using spell slots you have of the appropriate level. The spells' spellcasting ability is the ability increased by this feat.

Comment: This is definitely a duplicate of the question you linked. I agree that there isn't a satisfactory answer to that question, particularly regarding the language in the Fey Touched feat that allows you to use spell slots to cast the spells, but does not tie the spells to any class. I would wager that at the time that question and its answers were written, there were no published feats that had that kind of language in them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

#### No, it is not a wizard spell for you

Rules as written, if it was a wizard (or any other class) spell for you, it would say so.  It does not, so it isn't.

There are numerous places where a character can gain a spell that is likewise not associated with a class, for instance, spells granted as racial features.

Contrast with features like the Cleric's Arcana Domain feature, Arcane Mastery, which contains the language (emphasis added):

> Like your other domain spells, they are always prepared and **count as cleric spells for you**.

The fey touched are not the only ones with this problem.  As I noted, there are multiple races that grant spells that are not associated with a class.

To me, this makes sense.  The Arcana cleric is getting a spell via clerical power, whereas the fey touched are getting a spell because, well, they're fey touched.

#### Talk to your DM

That said, is it an unreasonable houserule to allow your wizard to treat it as a wizard spell?

Probably not, but of course, doing so allows tricks, although I think, fairly minor ones.  Allowing you to treat it as a wizard spell allows for Order of the Scribe damage-swapping, and allows you to create a scroll of it.  Neither are overpowered.

If it feels overly generous to allow the Order of Scribes wizard to just make it a wizard spell, perhaps some time and research would be needed for the scribe wizard to essentially research it as a wizard spell, but that's entirely up to the DM.