# Can a Wild Magic sorcerer trigger Wild Magic Surges with rituals?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, sorcerer, rituals, wild-magic

Wild Magic Surges may only trigger after casting a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher. By default, sorcerers cannot cast spells as rituals, but if they take the Ritual Caster feat, they can (for the list of a chosen class, including sorcerer).

There are 4 ritual spells on the sorcerer spell list: *Detect Magic*, *Comprehend Languages*, *Water Breathing*, and *Water Walk*.

Provided that a Wild Magic sorcerer takes the Ritual Caster feat with the sorcerer class option, can they then trigger Wild Magic Surges upon casting any of these 4 spells as a ritual?

Comment: Related, maybe even a duplicate: [Could a Wild Magic Surge be triggered by a Wild Magic Sorcerer using a Magic Initiate spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107253/could-a-wild-magic-surge-be-triggered-by-a-magic-initiate-spell)

Answer (score 17):

### Yes, they can trigger Wild Magic Surges in this way

Performing a ritual is still casting a spell (you even have to take the Cast a Spell action every turn). Since the Wild Magic Surge feature does not limit it to "when you cast a sorcerer spell with a 1st or higher level spell slot", any form of casting a sorcerer spell can trigger it.