# Does a Wild Magic Surge trigger at the beginning or the end of the casting of a spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, sorcerer, wild-magic

This is, in some way, a follow-up to this question: [Can you trigger Wild Magic Surges with rituals?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/111884/can-you-trigger-wild-magic-surges-with-rituals)

Some spells take longer than an action to cast (the best example is a ritual, which takes 10 minutes).

It is possible, as a [Wild Magic sorcerer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic) (PHB p. 103-104), to have access to sorcerer spells that take longer than an action to cast (notably, by taking the [Ritual Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/ritual-caster) feat and choosing the sorcerer class).

My question is: if the DM agrees for a Surge to happen upon casting a spell with a casting time of longer than an action, when could the Surge happen; at the beginning (first turn of casting, therefore allowing a Surge even if the long-time casting is somehow interrupted before its completion) or the end (last turn of casting)?

The ability says "immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher", but if I'm not mistaken, for longer casting times, you must take the "Cast a Spell" action every turn, hence why the wording makes me wonder when the Surge could happen.

Answer (score 19):

## At the end of the casting of a spell

The important thing is the quote you mention in your question:

> immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher (PHB, pg. 103)

It says "after you cast", so any time before that you are *casting* the spell, and only once the spell's casting has been completed have you *cast* the spell.

Answer (score 11):

## After the spell has been cast completely

As you noted, the language from the PHB(Page 103)

> Immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level
>   or higher

You can also reference Chapter 11 Spellcasting rules (PHB, 202):

> Most spells require a single action to cast, but some
>   spells require a bonus action, a reaction, or much more
>   time to cast.
>
> ...
>
> If your concentration is broken, the spell fails,
>   but you don’t expend a spell slot.

This suggests that a spell has not been cast until has completed casting.