# If the Feywild Shard magic item's Wild Magic Surge results in a spell, does that replace the initial triggering spell, or occur in addition to it?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, magic-items, metamagic, wild-magic

*Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 127) includes a magic item called the [*Feywild shard*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/feywild-shard). The relevant part of its description states:

> When you use a Metamagic option on a spell while you are holding or wearing the shard, you can roll on the Wild Magic Surge table in the *Player's Handbook*. If the result is a spell, it is too wild to be affected by your Metamagic, and if it normally requires concentration, it doesn't require concentration in this case; the spell lasts for its full duration.

This part is the one that some in my group don't agree on:

- My reading: You cast a spell that is being affected by Metamagic. You
  then choose to roll on the table. If the resulting effect listed on
  the table is then also a spell, it is separate from the original
  spell and has the two listed added conditions (Metamagic can't be
  used on it, and it doesn't require concentration).
- The others think that if the result of the roll on the Wild Magic
  Surge table is a spell, it replaces the original spell, and the
  original Metamagic option you chose doesn't affect it.

Which interpretation is correct?

Comment: Related: "[Does a Wild Magic Surge trigger at the beginning or the end of the casting of a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128248)"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### You are correct: it's an additional spell, separate from the one that triggered the Wild Magic Surge.

The effect of the *Feywild shard* magic item is triggered when you use a Metamagic option. All but two Metamagic options trigger when you cast a spell; Empowered Spell triggers when you roll damage for a spell, and [Seeking Spell](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/tcoe/sorcerer#SeekingSpell) (TCoE, p. 66) triggers when you make an attack roll for a spell and miss.

In all cases, any trigger that would take effect when a Metamagic option is used would take place at least after the initial spell has finished being cast. This means the potential resulting spell from a Wild Magic Surge coming from the *Feywild shard* would take place after the effects/concentration of the initial spell have already begun, and would not retroactively cancel the previous spell.

Also of note, the same 2 conditions mentioned in the description of the *Feywild shard* are mentioned in the [Wild Magic](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic) Sorcerer's [Wild Magic Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagicSurge-381) feature (*PHB*, p. 103):

> If that effect is a spell, it is too wild to be affected by your Metamagic, and if it normally requires concentration, it doesn't require concentration in this case; the spell lasts for its full duration.

This, too, is referring to the result of a roll on the Wild Magic Surge table; the relevant portion of the *Feywild shard*'s description uses (almost) exactly the same wording as the Wild Magic Surge feature description.