# Can Tides of Chaos reset in one turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, class-feature, sorcerer, wild-magic

The rules for Tides of Chaos are:

> Starting at 1st level, you can manipulate the forces of chance and chaos to gain advantage on one attack roll, ability check, or saving throw. Once you do so you must finish a long rest before you use this feature again.

> Any time before you regain the use of this feature, the DM can have you roll on the Wild Magic Surge table immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher. You then regain the use of this feature.

Is it possible for the DM to immediately reset Tides of Chaos?  Consider the following turn:

1. I declare I'm using ToC to gain advantage on my next attack.  I mark it as spent and have the ToC "buff"
2. I cast Chaos Bolt with advantage.  T
3. Because I just cast a 1st level spell, my DM has me roll on the surge table and reset ToC

Is there something I'm missing in the order of operations that would prevent this?  [The related question here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/128248/does-a-wild-magic-surge-trigger-at-the-beginning-or-the-end-of-the-casting-of-a) says that the spell cast completes before you roll to check Wild Magic Surge so I assume the same applies to ToC.  It seems wrong that its possible to constantly reset advantage as long as you have spell slots, but perhaps its allowed because its up to the DM to control it.

Comment: Related (do these answer your question): "[Does a Wild Magic Surge trigger at the beginning or the end of the casting of a spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/128248)" and "[How do Wild Magic Surge and Tides of Chaos interact](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/46216)"

Comment: The first question makes me lean towards my interpretation as correct, as the wild magic roll triggering *before* the cast ends would prevent the rapid reset.  The second question unfortunately doesn't help me, it deals with answering if casting a spell can trigger one or both between ToC and Wild Magic Surge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### This Works

What you've proposed is completely legitimate and as you rightly point out, the DM has control over when surges occur, which I think should be limited to just when a surge is going to disrupt a scene that's on rails.

As I've stated [in this other answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/144396/31402), WMS requires that you have a permissive DM, otherwise there's almost no point to playing one because you'll hardly ever see your features being used. Compare this to the other core sorcerous origin, Draconic Bloodline, which gets "always-on" features in the form of increased hit points and AC. If your WM sorcerer isn't rolling regularly on the surge table and cycling Tides of Chaos for regular Advantage, then you're not keeping up with the other origin.

Comment: My DM actively encourages WMS and has pulled me aside to say he wants it to go off as often as possible, so in that context it seemed OP to constantly have advantage.  But if its DM reliant then I'll take my advantage on every chaos bolt with pleasure.