# Can the 1st-level spell learned through the Aberrant Dragonmark feat trigger a Wild Magic Surge?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting, sorcerer, wild-magic

I'm playing a Wild magic sorcerer and it occurred to me that the 1st-level spell added from the Aberrant Dragonmark feat could potentially trigger a Wild Magic Surge.

Is this the case, and can I use my other spell slots or pact magic slots to cast the 1st-level spell learned through this feat?

Comment: Related, possible dupes: [Could a Wild Magic Surge be triggered by a Wild Magic Sorcerer using a Magic Initiate spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/107253/33569) (assumes sorc list for Magic Initiate), [Are spells learned from feats considered to be associated with your class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110954/33569), [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182/33569), [If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot, can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102875/33569)

Comment: https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Proc

Comment: Note that "sorcerer spell list" is a game term with a specific meaning. Did you not mean "(list of) known sorcerer spells"?

Comment: I've made some changes to the title and body to better reflect what I understood the question to be. Are these changes okay?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Can the spell from Aberrant Dragonmark trigger a Wild Magic Surge?

Yes. First, observe the trigger condition for [Wild Magic Surge](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic):

> Once per turn, the DM can have you roll a d20 immediately after you cast **a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher**.

Next, observe the language of [Aberrant Dragonmark](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/aberrant-dragonmark):

> In addition, choose a 1st-level spell from the sorcerer spell list.

In similar fashion to [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107253/could-a-wild-magic-surge-be-triggered-by-a-wild-magic-sorcerer-using-a-magic-ini#107256), the spell learned *is* a sorcerer spell, so it is eligible for triggering a Wild Magic Surge.

#### Can I use my other spell slots to cast the spell?

Yes. The *Sage Advice Compendium* contains a [ruling about the Magic Initiate feat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/sac/sage-advice-compendium#MagicInitiate) that applies in this case as well:

> **If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st-level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?**
> Yes, but only if the class you pick for the feat is one of your classes. For example, if you pick sorcerer and you are a sorcerer, the Spellcasting feature for that class tells you that you can use your spell slots to cast the sorcerer spells you know, so you can use your spell slots to cast the 1st-level sorcerer spell you learn from Magic Initiate. Similarly, if you are a wizard and pick that class for the feat, you learn a 1st-level wizard spell, which you could add to your spellbook and subsequently prepare.

Since the spell learned from Aberrant Dragonmark *is* a sorcerer spell, you can use your sorcerer spell slots to cast it, as confirmed by this ruling form the *Sage Advice Compendium*. Additionally, [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/102876/62294) outlines a different but applicable argument that draws the same conclusion without consulting *Sage Advice*.

Since you did mention pact slots, you would also be able to cast the spell using one of your pact slots. The [multiclass spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting) rules say:

> **Pact Magic.** If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.