# What counts as a sorcerer spell for the purposes of the Wild Magic sorcerer's Wild Magic Surge feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, spellcasting, sorcerer, wild-magic

The Wild Magic sorcerer's Wild Magic Surge feature states (PHB, p. 103):

> Starting when you choose this origin at 1st level, your spellcasting can unleash surges of untamed magic. Immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher, the DM can have you roll a d20. If you roll a 1, roll on the Wild Magic Surge table to create a random magical effect. A Wild Magic Surge can happen once per turn.
>
> If a Wild Magic effect is a spell, it's too wild to be affected by Metamagic. If it normally requires concentration, it doesn't require concentration in this case; the spell lasts for its full duration.

What fulfills the requirements of a "sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher"?

A few options that I can think of for defining a "sorcerer spell":

1. **Any spell that you've learned from Sorcerer and that you're
   casting through the Spellcasting feature.**
   This is my idea of the default answer. A sorcerer spell is a spell
   you've learned as a sorcerer and are casting as a sorcerer.
2. **Any spell that you've learned from Sorcerer.**
   This is also reasonable - but it opens the door to casting spells
   through magic items, such as the *Cape of the Mountebank*,
   triggering wild magic surges.
3. **Any spell on the Sorcerer spell list.**
   Still reasonable. This would mean that learning the spell *Hold
   Person* through the Bard's learned spells (e.g. by multiclassing
   into Bard) and casting it could trigger a wild magic surge, as it's
   a spell that's both on the Bard's spell list and the Sorcerer's.

Comment: Thank you! That eliminates the last possibility, where a Bard learns a spell from the Sorcerer's spell list

Comment: Extremely related: "[What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182)"

Comment: Related (not quite a duplicate, but the issue is touched on in one of your possible interpretations): [Can a sorcerer spell cast from a magic item trigger a Wild Magic Surge?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/131710/33569)

Comment: Your question seems to be a duplicate of this one: [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182/33569). Your specific question is explicitly covered as part of that Q&A. Please check to see if it matches/answers your question; if not, please edit to clarify how your question is distinct from that one.

Comment: Nope, it looks like that question covers my question nicely. Thanks V2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit: Author's Note
When this question was closed as a duplicate, I copied my answer from here to the [original question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell/177772#177772).  Since then, I have edited the answer there as I have continued to research and think about the question.  However, even while this question is closed, my answer here has continued to receive votes.  I would encourage readers to follow the link to my answer there, as it is more recent and more complete.

### Sorcerer spells are spells you know from being a sorcerer

There are (at least) two ways to resolve this.  There is a clear, direct answer: **Any spell you cast that is on the sorcerer spell list counts as a sorcerer spell** (*ie*, your last option).  While this has the advantages of both being simple and of being a response directed at the question itself, it has the disadvantage of being largely based on (now unofficial) tweets from Jeremy Crawford.  If you wish to go that route, I encourage you to read the answers that use these quotes at ["What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?"](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell/106192#106192) (Thank you to Medix2 and David Coffron for that link).  I choose not to follow that path for reasons other than it being unofficial.  First, this is a complex question and I don't think all the nuances and caveats lend themselves to explanation within a tweet character limit.  Second, I am uncomfortable with the logical conclusion that follows - an individual spell you cast that is on two different spell lists is simultaneously a spell of both of those classes.  And third, applied broadly it contradicts what *is* an official Sage Advice answer (see below).

For me then, the way to resolve this is to look at what is actually within the the text of official sources such as the PHB and Sage Advice.  Unfortunately, this approach relies on interpreting passages that were not explicitly directed at the question itself, and interpretations can vary.

#### Spells you know on your list because of your class Spellcasting ability

To start, your sorcerer spells are spells off the sorcerer spell list *that you know* because you are a sorcerer (having the Spellcasting ability because you are of the sorcerer class).

"Sorcerer: Spellcasting" (PHB 101; emphasis mine)

> **Spell Slots** The Sorcerer table shows how many spell slots you have to cast your spells of 1st level and higher. To cast one of these **sorcerer spells**, you must expend a slot of the spell’s level or higher...
> **Spells Known of 1st Level and Higher** The Spells Known column of the Sorcerer table shows when you learn more **sorcerer spells** of your choice...Additionally, when you gain a level in this class,
> you can choose one of the **sorcerer spells you know** and replace it with another **spell from the sorcerer spell list**, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

Notice the subtle distinction between "sorcerer spells" and a "spell from the sorcerer spell list".  A spell becomes a sorcerer spell for you *when you know it*.  Just being on the sorcerer spell list is not enough; it does not become a sorcerer spell for you *until* you know it.

This interpretation is supported by the text in the (optional) [Multiclassing Rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/customization-options#Spellcasting) (emphasis mine)

> You determine what spells you know and can prepare for each class individually, as if you were a single-classed member of that class...**Each spell you know and prepare is associated with one of your classes**, and you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you cast the spell.

It is a matter of interpretation how much one ascribes to the phrase "associated with".  I choose to believe it means that knowing a spell through being a sorcerer makes it a sorcerer spell.

#### Spells you gain access to *not* through the Spellcasting feature of your class

If something besides your class Spellcasting feature grants you the ability to cast a spell, typically it will tell you what class of spell it is.

For example, the Cleric's Domain feature (PHB 58):

> If you have a domain spell that doesn’t appear on the cleric spell list, the spell is nonetheless a cleric spell for you.

Here, although the spell does not appear on the cleric spell list, and in fact appears on another spell list, it is still a cleric spell because it says it is. (I would argue that the underlying principle is that it is because knowledge of the spell is granted through a cleric class feature, although it does not say that explicitly).  Thus, if a specific class feature gave you a spell, it would be a sorcerer spell if it said it was. (See also the Druid's Circle spells and the Bard's Magical Secrets)

You might also learn a spell through the optional rules of feats, which are *not* a class feature.  However, these will still typically imply what kind of spell you are getting.

"Feats: Magic Initiate" (PHB 168)

> Choose a class: bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, warlock, or wizard. You learn two cantrips of your choice from that class’s spell list. In addition, choose one 1st-level spell from that same list. You learn that spell and can cast it at its lowest level. Once you cast it, you must finish a long rest before you can cast it again. Your spellcasting ability for these spells depends on the class you chose: Charisma for bard, sorcerer, or warlock; Wisdom for cleric or druid: or
> Intelligence for wizard.

This stops short of saying the spells you learn are spells of the class you choose.  Fortunately there is a [Sage Advice Compendium](http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/sage-advice/sage-advice-compendium) that more explicitly addresses Magic Initiate:

> **If you have spell slots, can you use them to cast the 1st-level spell you learn with the Magic Initiate feat?** Yes, but only if the class you pick for the feat is one of your classes. For example, if you pick sorcerer and you are a sorcerer, the Spellcasting feature for that class tells you that you can use your spell slots to cast the sorcerer spells you know, so you can use your spell slots to cast the 1st-level sorcerer spell you learn from Magic Initiate. Similarly, if you are a wizard and pick that class for the feat, you learn a 1st-level wizard spell, which you could add to your spellbook and subsequently prepare.
> In short, you must follow your character’s normal spellcasting rules, which determine whether you can expend spell slots on the 1st-level spell you learn from Magic Initiate.

Here, we are told explicitly that a spell counts as a sorcerer spell not because you knew it through a sorcerer class feature, but because you deliberately learned it from the sorcerer spell class list.  Had the same spell also been on another class list as well as that of the sorcerer, and you learned it through Magic Initiate as the other class, it would **not** count as a sorcerer spell.  (See also [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/107253/could-a-wild-magic-surge-be-triggered-by-a-wild-magic-sorcerer-using-a-magic-ini?rq=1) and [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/110954/are-spells-learned-from-feats-considered-to-be-associated-with-your-class), and the "Ritual Caster" feat).

You ask specifically about magic items, and here it gets more difficult.  Magic items that grant you the ability to cast spells do not typically tell you what kind of spells they are, although it is clear that it is you who are casting the spell, not the item.

"Activating an Item; Spells" (DMG 141); emphasis mine

> Some magic items **allow the user to cast a spell** from the item...A magic item, such as certain staffs, may require you to use your own spellcasting ability when **you cast a spell from the item.** If you have more than one spellcasting ability, you choose which one to use with the item.

While you are certainly the one casting the spell, is it a sorcerer spell?  Since my resolution of this emphasizes spells you know, I would say a spell you cast from an item is a sorcerer spell *if* it is a spell you already *know from being a sorcerer*.  However, this is my interpretation, and others disagree (see [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/131710/can-a-sorcerer-spell-cast-from-a-magic-item-trigger-a-wild-magic-surge?rq=1)).

#### What if you know a spell through more than one means?

(See also [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/177378/does-learning-the-same-spell-from-different-sources-allow-it-to-benefit-from-bon/177379#177379))  If you are multiclassed and have access to a spell from another class that is also on the sorcerer spell list, you still can't cast it as a sorcerer unless you *know it* through being a sorcerer ("Each spell you know and prepare is associated with one of your classes").

But if you know the spell both as a sorcerer and as another class, is it a sorcerer spell?  I would say that you make that decision at the moment you cast it, based on the multiclassing rules: "you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you cast the spell".

I realize that 'your spellcasting ability' (*ie*, Charisma) is not 'your ability to use Spellcasting' (*ie*, a class feature), and I recognize that a spell's *class* being determined at the moment of casting is also my interpretation.  But the precedent of, when a spell could be sourced from multiple classes, choosing the spellcasting ability as a proxy for class at the time of casting seems clear enough to me.

Thus, I would say that **Any spell on the sorcerer spell list that you *know* from being a sorcerer is a sorcerer spell, *if* you cast it as a sorcerer.  If a feature gives you the ability to cast a spell and explicitly references the sorcerer class, the spell can also be a sorcerer spell, *if* you cast it as a sorcerer**.

Comment: This answer could be improved by directly addressing the conflicting arguments found in [this related answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/106192/41726). The Multiclassing rules you quote don't directly say that the spell counts as one of your classes *when cast*, only that it's associated with one. Also, the sorcerer may not be multiclassed at all since it is a variant rule

Comment: @DavidCoffron Edited.  Please take another look.

Comment: Might be worthwhile to link the question for the last section: [Does learning the same spell from different sources allow it to benefit from bonuses from all sources?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/177379)

Comment: @ThomasMarkov I had cited that as a related question in a comment to the OP's question.  Per your suggestion, I have now moved the link into my answer and deleted it from the comment, and done the same with other related comments.  Thank you.