# What is an "artificer spell" for Infuse Magic?

Tags: dnd-5e, unearthed-arcana, artificer

The *Infused Magic* feature from *Unearthed Arcana: Artificer* says:

> Starting at 4th level, you gain the ability to channel your artificer
>   spells into objects for later use. When you cast an artificer spell
>   with a casting time of 1 action, you can increase its casting time to
>   1 minute.

What exactly is an artificer spell? Are only those spells I choose at first level (or when I level up as Artificer) "artificer spells"? Or are all spells I can cast "artificer spells", as long as they are on the artificer spell list and I'm high enough level.

An example. I’m a Level 4 Artificer, Level 1 Wizard. (I know that UA Classes are not meant for multiclassing, but I did it anyway). If I haven’t chosen Disguise Self as one of my Artificer spells, but I have it in my spellbook, would I be able to infuse Disguise Self into an object? Would I have to prepare Disguise Self as a wizard, in order to infuse it as an artificer? Or would it be enough to have it in my spellbook?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying; I've updated the question further just slightly. I've also edited out the "thanks" at the end since we prefer to avoid sign-offs and other formalities so as to make the question's content purely devoted to the question itself. Also, belatedly -- Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here, and when you reach 20 rep, you can join us in [chat].

Comment: Related(/duplicate?): [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a class spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell)

Comment: There is a slightly updated version on DM's Guild, but I believe that part didn't change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### As per RAW - No, you can't use the spells in your spellbook as *Artificer Spells*

In general *Artificer Spells*, just like *Wizard Spells* or *Warlock Spells* are those spells that are in the list of available spells for the class.

There are exceptions to this rule. Certain class features might state that your list of available spells is bigger - for example Warlocks choose a patron that grants them certain spells that are not in the list of Warlock Spells that you would find at the end of the PHB. But: This feature states that these spells count as *Warlock Spells* for you.

The Wizard's spellbook for example allows you to transcribe *Wizard Spells* into the spellbook.

As such you can normally **not** infuse spells that are in your spellbook. You have to learn them through a class feature of your Artificer class that explicitly says that the spell counts as an *Artificer Spell*. Otherwise you would learn *Wizard Spells* when leveling your Wizard side, *Artificer Spells* when leveling your Artificer side and you could transcribe *Wizard Spells* into your spellbook - not *Artificer Spells*. Even if they are in both lists, they don't count for both at the same time.

#### Unearthed Arcana is playtesting material

Usual caveat: as you said yourself, Unearthed Arcana is not balanced for multiclassing and as such there may be problems when it comes to situations like these. Test the playtesting material and if you think something is too powerful/not powerful enough you should discuss with your DM how to adjust it.

Saying that every spell in the spellbook that is also in the list of *Artificer Spells* counts as an *Artificer Spell* for the purpose of class features from the Artificer when multiclassing is a possible solution. Or saying that you can transcribe spells for all classes where you have at least one level, so that you could treat the spell as an *Artificer Spell*.

But here you are in homebrew territory and this might have unintended side effects.