# Can a bard cast Identify as a ritual without having the Ritual Caster feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic, rituals

Well I'm really confused by how rituals work, and the idea of the Ritual Caster feat/wizard bonus.

If I learn the spell [*identify*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/identify), it seems to me I can cast this as a ritual to not spend a spell slot?

If I could, what is the big idea of the [Ritual Caster](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/feats/ritual-caster) feat (PHB p. 169)? Just the ability to learn 2 more spells?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### For a bard, yes. The feat can be taken by other classes though

In order to cast a spell as a ritual a feature must allow you to do so. Bards have Ritual Casting as part of their Spellcasting feature:

> You can cast any bard spell you know as a ritual if that spell has the ritual tag.

... but not every spellcaster has this. Some examples include Eldritch Knights and Sorcerers. Also, non-casters can take the feat as long as they have the requires ability scores.

Comment: And sorcerers,  and arcane tricksters, paladins,  and rangers

Comment: What is a "bard spell" btw? As far as I know Identify isn't solely used by the bard, and it doesn't feel really "bardy" either.

Comment: @paul23 Any spell you learn from being a bard is a bard spell essentially.  See [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell)

Answer (score 9):

### Bards can

Not all spellcasters can cast ritually, this is an additional feature some of them have. Look for it in the class description after "spellcasting". Bards have such a feature, so if one were to learn *identify*, they could cast it (if they have the material component).

The Ritual Caster feat has multiple advantages:

1. The character does not have to be a spellcaster to take it. Even a
   fighter can choose it and learn spells.
2. If you choose a spellcasting class you have levels in, you can cast all ritual spells you already know as rituals.
3. You can add spells to your ritual book. Most classes only earn spells when they level up, with this you can have more spells.

Comment: Another advantage to add to the list is that you can choose a different spellcasting class than the one you belong to and add those ritual spells to your repertoire. A cleric who knows wizard ritual spells, or vice versa.