# Can a character replace their Magic Initiate spells using the Spellcasting feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, feats, class-feature

The feat Magic Initiate lets you learn a 1st level spell:

> You learn that spell and can cast it at its lowest level. Once you cast it, you must finish a long rest before you can cast it again using this feat.

Depending on the class you choose, [this spell will count as a [class] spell](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell) for the purpose of other features.

The Spellcasting class feature is one such feature that mentions [class] spells for classes like Rangers, Bards, and Sorcerers (among others):

> Additionally, when you gain a level in this class, you can choose one of the [class] spells you know and replace it with another spell from the [class] spell list, which also must be of a level for which you have spell slots.

**Could you replace the spell from Magic Initiate with another spell from that class's class spell list upon gaining a level in that class?

 If you replaced the spell with a higher level one "for which you have spell slots", could you then still cast it once using the feat (i.e. without using a spell slot) between long rests?**

---

I'd prefer answers from a RAW perspective, as I'm aware of [Jeremy Crawford's tweet](https://www.twitter.com/JeremyECrawford/status/906265664951697408) indicating a sort of RAI perspective:

> Magic Initiate doesn't provide a way to replace its spells

Comment: Related: [Can Spells from the Magic Initiate feat be swapped out for different ones?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/134996)

Comment: Related: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/49731/can-you-retrain-the-magic-initiate-spell