# does undying servitude add animate dead to the warlock spell list?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, warlock, undead, necromancy

does the invocation undying servitude add animate dead to the warlock spell list? it says you may cast it without spending a spell slot once a day, however, does "once a day" apply to the casting or casting without a spell slot?

Comment: I don’t think this is a dupe.

Comment: At least related: "[Does Confusion cast via the Dreadful Word invocation count as a warlock spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141536)" and "[What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182)" and "[If you have the ability to cast a spell without a spell slot, can you cast that spell using a spell slot?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102875)" and "[Can I use spell slots to cast the spell granted from the Fey Teleportation feat additional times?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/110944)"

Comment: @Odo Notably, if they are; it is a duplicate of [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/102875); I'll add that to the list to be safe