# Can I use my best spellcasting ability for Eldritch Adept?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, spellcasting, ability-scores, eldritch-invocations

Suppose I am a multiclass character that has "Spellcasting" from multiple sources and I take the Eldritch Adept (Tasha, p.79)  feat. Can I then use my best Spell Save DC for spells that that I have gained through Invocations in this way?

For example, a Bard/Cleric that has a Spell Save DC of 12 and 15, casts "Silent Image" (PHB p.276) using the "Misty Visions" invocation (PHB p.111).  Is the difficulty to investigate the image a DC 12 or 15?

I'd assume I can simply take the best option, since this seems to not be specified. Is that correct?

Now, what if my multiclass character is a Warlock/Cleric, and the Warlock's Spell Save DC is the lower one, can I still use the Cleric's Spell Save DC for spells that I cast through invocations from this feat?

Comment: Possibly a couple of questions here. But have you taken into account the fact that Eldritch Adept only allows invocations that have no prerequisites? Its possible that this will exclude ones that grant spells anyway (at least, spells that require a DC) so your questions could be moot.

Comment: Yes, so the example gives "Misty Visions"/"Silent Image", which has no requirements. Also, it's really just one question: "Can you use your best spell save DC, when you have multiple spellcasting sources, even when one of these is a Warlock"

Comment: Related: "[Does Confusion cast via the Dreadful Word invocation count as a warlock spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141536)" and perhaps "[Are the spells learned from the "Touched" feats considered class spells when cast using spell slots?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177773)"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

### Spell save DCs are based on the class with which a spell is associated

Generally, every spell you acquire will be a result of a feature/levelling up of a particular class. That spell will be associated with that class and will use the spellcasting modifier for that class for the DC when you cast it.

This is explained in the [multiclassing rules](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting):

> Each spell you know and prepare is associated with one of your
> classes, and you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you
> cast the spell.

Now, Warlock invocations are a bit of an edge case perhaps. But, as Ryan C. Thompson points out in the comments, when you learn an invocation it is "from the Warlock class". Hence would use the Warlock spellcasting rules that specify Charisma to calculate any save DC.

Comment: The feat says "you learn one Eldritch Invocation option of your choice **from the warlock class**", so I think that establishes that any features or spells granted by the invocation are associated with the warlock class.

Comment: @RyanC.Thompson. Thanks. I've amended my last paragraph.

Comment: What if you're not multiclassing? Like a barbarian that takes the Eldritch Adept>Misty Visions?

Comment: @SpiderWaffle the feat's prerequisite requires the Spellcasting or Pact Magic feature. A pure class Barbarian can't take it.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker, good point. But what even is "spellcasting" as a prerequisite? Is that clearing define anywhere? What you just took a feat that gives you spellcasting that doesn't have that prerequisite, or got spellcasting from your race?

Comment: @SpiderWaffle The Spellcasting and Pact Magic features are part of a class, listed in the Class Features section of Bard, Cleric, Wizard, and so on. There are many ways to get spells, but only certain classes get the Feature.

Comment: @GreenstoneWalker Ya I found stack on that, it seems to be somewhat assumed, or post-edict, Crawford and friends could have afforded to be more explicit about those initially.
I could see someone wondering if their "Innate Spellcasting" is "Spellcasting"

Answer (score 11):

*(Note: This answer was written prior to the December 2021 erratum. I still believe that this is the correct interpretation for the general case of class features gained through means other than class levels, and that the erratum represents a specific exception to the general rule.)*

### Spells from warlock class features use your Charisma

In the class description for the [warlock](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/warlock#ClassFeatures) (as with every other spellcasting class), there is only one definition of your spellcasting ability:

> ###### Spellcasting Ability
>
> Charisma is your spellcasting ability for your warlock spells, so you use your Charisma whenever a spell refers to your spellcasting ability.

Many Eldritch Invocations grant you the ability to cast spells without telling you which spellcasting ability to use. However, any time a warlock class feature references your spellcasting ability (even indirectly through the description of a spell granted by that feature), it *must* be referring to your Charisma score, because *there is no other spellcasting ability it could possibly be referring to.* Having levels in one or more other classes doesn't change this, as explained in the rules for [multiclassing](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/customization-options#Spellcasting):

> Each spell you know and prepare is associated with one of your classes, and you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you cast the spell.

The Eldritch Adept feat says (emphasis added):

> [...] you learn one Eldritch Invocation option of your choice **from the warlock class**.

This is a bit redundant, of course, because as far as I know there are no Eldritch Invocations *not* associated with the warlock class, but it makes the class association explicit: you are gaining a feature specifically associated with the warlock class, which means that **the relevant spellcasting ability must be the one defined in the warlock class: Charisma.**

In your case, since your bard spell save DC is 12, then your warlock spell save DC is probably *also* 12, since they both use Charisma as their spellcasting ability. But note that you are *not* using your bard spell save DC; you are just using another spell save DC that happens to be the same. For example, if you attuned a [Reveler’s Concertina](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/revelers-concertina), the spell save DC of your bard spells would become 14, but your warlock spell save DC would remain at 12. Alternatively, even if you had no bard levels at all (and hence no bard spell save DC), your warlock spell save DC would *still* be 12.

Comment: Perhaps helpful: "[Does Confusion cast via the Dreadful Word invocation count as a warlock spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/141536)". Although [the less upvoted answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/141544) *completely* disagrees with your answer XD

Comment: Great answer, unfortunately I can only accept one.  @Medix2, an interesting question/answer there as well.

Comment: @svenema I feel like this is the better answer as it gets straight to the point about it being from a warlock features, and doesn't muddy the waters by talking about multiclassing

Comment: @AncientSwordRage It does muddy the waters by talking about multiclassing.

Answer (score 7):

#### You choose one of Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma when you take this feat.

In December 2021, an [errata to *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything*](https://media.wizards.com/2021/dnd/downloads/TCE-Errata.pdf) answered this exact question (emphasis mine):

> ***Eldritch Adept (pg. 79).*** The first sentence has been re-
> placed with the following: “Studying occult lore, you learn
> one Eldritch Invocation option of your choice from the
> warlock class. **Your spellcasting ability for the invocation
> is Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma (choose when you
> select this feat).**”

So if your chosen invocation comes with a spell to cast, the spellcasting modifier for that spell is the ability chosen when you selected the feat, either Intelligence, Wisdom, or Charisma.

Answer (score -2):

## Use a spell save DC based on your Charisma

Whenever you cast a spell using an ability given to you by a class, you use that class's spell save DC calculation. While the *Eldritch Adept* feat is not itself a class feature, it grants Eldritch Invocations to characters, and those invocations are Warlock class features.

So use the spell save DC calculation given in Pact Magic for Warlocks:

> **Spell save DC** = 8 + your proficiency bonus + your Charisma modifier

For your Bard/Cleric example character, you'd use DC 12, since your Warlock spell save DC will be based on the same attribute as your Bard spell save DC. For a character without Charisma based spellcasting, you might get a whole new DC just for spells granted to you by your new Eldritch Invocation.

Comment: Do you have a source (PHB, Sage Advice, etc.) that state "Whenever you cast a spell using an ability given to you by a class, you use that class's spell save DC calculation"? I'm not familiar with that rule.

Comment: @svenema I suggest that you check the Magic Initiate feat and the multiclassing rules. Also, the way you framed the question isn't how the PHB is written. The default game is feat less and multiclass-less, so any spell caster will only use their class spell casting ability.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast that's not true, all racial spell casting comes with a specific spell casting ability. So you could play feat less and multiclass-less and take say the Gnome (Forest) race from the PHB and have an intelligence spell casting ability for this minor illusion, but also have minor illusion from taking sorcerer and have a charisma spell casting ability for that one. No feats or multiclassesing or even extra source books.