# Does Wild Magic Surge trigger off of spells on the Sorcerer spell list, if I learned them from another class?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, multi-classing, sorcerer, wild-magic

Let's say I am a Bard, and I have 1 level in Sorcerer, giving me a Sorcerous Origin, and I choose Wild Magic. **Does Wild Magic Surge trigger off of any spell I cast that just so happens to be on the Sorcerer spell list?**

Example:
If I cast Charm Person, a spell obtainable by Sorcerers and Bards, but I obtained that spell by leveling up as a Bard, does that count as a Sorcerer spell when I cast it?  Or are the only spells that count as Sorcerer spells the ones I gain when I take the level of sorcerer or gain levels in the sorcerer class?

Comment: Related: [What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/106182/what-makes-a-spell-being-cast-considered-to-be-a-class-spell)

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already. and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 10):

## It can trigger if you learned the spell as a sorcerer.

The following is buried in [the Multiclassing rules for Spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/phb/customization-options#MulticlassSpellcaster):

> Each spell you know and prepare is associated with one of your classes, and you use the spellcasting ability of that class when you cast the spell.

Then check the wording of [the Wild Magic Surge feature](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/sorcerer#WildMagic):

> Once per turn, the DM can have you roll a d20 immediately after you cast a sorcerer spell of 1st level or higher.

Regarding the wording within the class, the spells you know as a sorcerer are your sorcerer spells. So if you know *charm person* (for example) as a sorcerer because you learned it from that class then your wild magic surge can trigger when you cast it. However, if you learned it as a bard, it will not trigger. Each spell is fundamentally associated with the class that granted you the spell, regardless of which list(s) it appears on or which spell slot you use to cast it.