# Question regarding Pact magic with multiclassing and a class specific bonus

Tags: dnd-5e, spellcasting, multi-classing

I play a  6 bard/ 4 warlock multiclass. My character recently obtained a rhythm makers drum +3, giving a +3 bonus to my bard spells' DC and rolls.

I am curious if I were to cast a spell I had taken on my warlock list (hold person) with a bard spell slot, would the bonus increase the DC? DnDB added the bonus to all my characters spells (I know that isn't right) but thought it may be applicable if a spell is on both lists.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related: "[Can I multiclass and cast a spell I already know as a different class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/115968)" and "[What makes a spell being cast considered to be a {class} spell?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/106182)" and somewhat: "[Can a multiclass character use either of its spellcasting modifiers for spells?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/132854)"

Comment: Also related: "[Does Wild Magic Surge trigger off of spells on the Sorcerer spell list, if I learned them from another class?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/143269)" and "[Does learning the same spell from different sources allow it to benefit from bonuses from all sources?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/177378)"

Answer (score 7):

**No**

The description for that item says it works for your bard spells and thus it only works for bard spells. This is one of the core principles of D&D 5E - everything does what their description says they do.

If you had the same spell as a bard then you could add the bonus from the drum but you can't use it for spells from other sources. If you could then you could arguably stack an item that increases warlock spell DC with one that increases bard spell DC.

It also doesn't matter what spell slot you use - there is no real difference according to the rules:

> Spell Slots. You determine your available spell slots by adding together all your levels in the bard, cleric, druid, sorcerer, and wizard classes, and half your levels (rounded down) in the paladin and ranger classes. Use this total to determine your spell slots by consulting the Multiclass Spellcaster table.

> Pact Magic. If you have both the Spellcasting class feature and the Pact Magic class feature from the warlock class, you can use the spell slots you gain from the Pact Magic feature to cast spells you know or have prepared from classes with the Spellcasting class feature, and you can use the spell slots you gain from the Spellcasting class feature to cast warlock spells you know.

Comment: You're not wrong, but it may help OP to show him where it says those things and why.

Comment: The last bit needs to be modified as certain features and abilities require the use of specific spell slots. Like Warlocks for example have spells specifically limited to using their slots. Can't use a bard slot for Eldritch Smite as an example.

Comment: @Lino Technically there's also one Ranger feature that requires Ranger spell slots... but that one probably just never got an errata :(

Comment: @Medix2 - I'm sorry but that's killing me. I'm legit laughing at that. Could you imagine being multi-classed Ranger/Druid, and getting screwed by that specific Ranger spell? Like just an extra middle finger to the Ranger for no apparent reason. LOL